# Saving contents of df.show() as a string in spark-scala app

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

I need to save the output of df.show() as a string so that i can email it directly.

For ex., the below example taken from official spark docs,:

```
val df = spark.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

// Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.show()
// +----+-------+
// | age|   name|
// +----+-------+
// |null|Michael|
// |  30|   Andy|
// |  19| Justin|
// +----+-------+
```

I need to save the above table as a string which is printed in the console. I did look at log4j to print the log, but couldnt come across any info on logging only the output.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: this has already been answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741035/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-output-of-sparks-dataset-show-method-as-a-string/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`scala.Console` has a `withOut` method for this kind of thing:

```
val outCapture = new ByteArrayOutputStream
Console.withOut(outCapture) {
  df.show()
}
val result = new String(outCapture.toByteArray)
```

Comment: I had a problem when running this due to a conflict with java.io, so I changed a line to `scala.Console.withOut(outCapture)` and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Workaround is  to redirect standard output to variable:

```
val baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
val ps =  new java.io.PrintStream(baos);

val oldPs = Console.out
Console.setOut(ps)
df.show()
val content = baos.toString()
Console.setOut(oldPs)
```

Note that I have one deprecation warning here.

You can also re-implement method `Dataset.showString`, which generated data. It uses `take` in background. Maybe it's also a good moment to create PR to make [`showString`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8b983243e45dfe2617c043a3229a7d87f4c4b44b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L241-L360) public? :)

Comment: Will try and update with comment.. looking at it right now.

Comment: Workaround given by T. Gawęda worked fine for me.