# Saving result of DataFrame show() to string in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to capture the result of *show* in pyspark, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124386/capturing-the-result-of-explain-in-pyspark) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546963/saving-contents-of-df-show-as-a-string-in-spark-scala-app?noredirect=1&lq=1). I was not able to find a solution with pyspark, only scala.

```python
df.show()
#+----+-------+
#| age|   name|
#+----+-------+
#|null|Michael|
#|  30|   Andy|
#|  19| Justin|
#+----+-------+
```

The ultimate purpose is to capture this as string inside my `logger.info`
I tried `logger.info(df.show())` which will only display on console.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can build a helper function using the same approach as shown in post you linked [Capturing the result of explain() in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124386/capturing-the-result-of-explain-in-pyspark). Just examine the [source code for `show()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.show) and observe that it is calling `self._jdf.showString()`.

The answer depends on which version of spark you are using, as the number of arguments to `show()` has changed over time.

#### Spark Version 2.3 and above

In version 2.3, the `vertical` argument was added.

```python
def getShowString(df, n=20, truncate=True, vertical=False):
    if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
        return(df._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    else:
        return(df._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))
```

#### Spark Versions 1.5 through 2.2

As of version 1.5, the `truncate` argument was added.

```python
def getShowString(df, n=20, truncate=True):
    if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
        return(df._jdf.showString(n, 20))
    else:
        return(df._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate)))
```

#### Spark Versions 1.3 through 1.4

The `show` function was first introduced in version 1.3.

```python
def getShowString(df, n=20):
    return(df._jdf.showString(n))
```

---

Now use the helper function as follows:

```python
x = getShowString(df)  # default arguments
print(x)
#+----+-------+
#| age|   name|
#+----+-------+
#|null|Michael|
#|  30|   Andy|
#|  19| Justin|
#+----+-------+
```

Or in your case:

```python
logger.info(getShowString(df))
```

Comment: Hmm I got an error showString does not exist. An error occurred while calling o10175.showString. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method showString([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)

Comment: @Kenny what version of spark (`print(spark.version)`)? You have to use the version of the function that is specific to your spark version.

Comment: ver 2.2 . Please disregard the error. I got mixed up between n and 20. There should be 2 params there. Great answer, thanks @pault

Comment: Unbelievable they didn't provide such helper functions themself yet, not even with the 3.x version.

Comment: It is working as expected. Thanks alot.