# DataFrame show string representation fails with showString(Integer, Boolean, Boolean) does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, python-3.8, pyspark

I'm trying to capture the string representation generated by the `show()` function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653609/saving-result-of-dataframe-show-to-string-in-pyspark), but it seems like the `showString` method is no longer public.

```
logger.info('\n{}'.format(raw_data._jdf.showString(20, False, False)))
```

is returning the following error trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxxxxx/SparkTest/main.py", line 63, in <module>
    logger.info('\n{}\n'.format(raw_data._jdf.showString(20, False, False)))
  File "xxxxxxxx/envs/SparkTest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "xxxxxxxx/envs/SparkTest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "xxxxxxxx/envs/SparkTest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 330, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o45.showString. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method showString([class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Boolean, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

is there another alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the method `showString(Integer, Boolean, Boolean)` does not exist. If you look at [`showString`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/30aaa5a3a1076ca52439a905274b1fcf498bc562/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L241) source code, it takes `Integer` as second argument but you're passing a `boolean`.

You want to set `truncate=False` so simply pass 0 in the second argument:

```
logger.info('\n{}'.format(raw_data._jdf.showString(20, 0, False)))
```