# How to output pyspark aggregation function results as a string?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am doing some data quality check using PySpark. What I want to achieve is output all results to a txt file. The basic code logic is as follows:

```
def data_quality_check(df):
    output = ''
    output += func1(df) # func1 and func2 return check results as strings
    output += func2(df)
    return output
```

The challenge I encountered is how to output aggregation results from pySpark dataframe. For example, I want to output a groupBy/count result using the following code:

```
output += 'Counts group by device type is : ' + str(df.groupBy('DEVICE_TYPE').count().show()) + '\n'
```

The output below is not what I expected:

```
Counts group by device type is : None
```

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: Another way to ask this question is how to save xx.show() results to text file? Thanks!

Comment: df.groupBy('DEVICE_TYPE').count().write.format('csv').save('test', mode="overwrite") should write into a file in csv format. Are you facing any issue with that?

Comment: @HussainBohra  Yes I can do that. Is there anyway that I can write multiple such strings into the same csv or txt file as the code runs? Thanks again!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input data and output file you are looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving result of DataFrame show() to string in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653609/saving-result-of-dataframe-show-to-string-in-pyspark)

Comment: @mck  Yes, that answered my question. Thank you all!